# moving a character through a method - python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to move a character by a certain distance by calling that method and the distance I want to move it by. So far I can determine the characters position by calling the function and placing my x and y values. When the user clicks a mouse. In the main method, i would want the move method to be called. Ive tried two implementations of move, first move and second move_c, neither work. Im using python3 and pygame

Any suggestions?

:

Heres my code

```
import pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class Vector():
    '''

            creates operations to handle vectors such
            as direction, position, and speed
        '''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self): # used for printing vectors
        return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return self.x
        elif key == 1:
            return self.y
        else:
            raise IndexError("This "+str(key)+" key is not a vector key!")

    def __sub__(self, o): # subtraction
        return Vector(self.x - o.x, self.y - o.y)

    def length(self): # get length (used for normalize)
        return math.sqrt((self.x**2 + self.y**2)) 

    def normalize(self): # divides a vector by its length
        l = self.length()
        if l != 0:
            return (self.x / l, self.y / l)
        return None



class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Class:
            creates a sprite
        Parameters:
            - self
        '''
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Images/green.png").convert() # load image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.speed = 10 # movement speed of the sprite
        self.speedX = 0 # speed in x direction
        self.speedY = 0 # speed in y direction
        self.target = None # starts off with no target

    def set_position(self, x,y):
        self.rect.centerx= x
        self.rect.centery= y
        self.rect.center=(self.rect.centery, self.rect.centery)

    def get_position(self):
        return self.rect.center


    def move(self, distance):
        if self.target:
            direction =self.get_direction(self.target)
            position = self.get_position() # create a vector from center x,y value
            direction = Vector(direction[0], direction[1]) # and one from the target x,y
            distance = target - position # get total distance between target and position
        return distance

    def get_direction(self, target):
        '''
        Function:
            takes total distance from sprite.center
            to the sprites target
            (gets direction to move)
        Returns:
            a normalized vector
        Parameters:
            - self
            - target
                x,y coordinates of the sprites target
                can be any x,y coorinate pair in
                brackets [x,y]
                or parentheses (x,y)
        '''
        if self.target: # if the square has a target
            position = Vector(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery) # create a vector from center x,y value
            target = Vector(target[0], target[1]) # and one from the target x,y
            self.dist = target - position # get total distance between target and position

            direction = self.dist.normalize() # normalize so its constant in all directions
            return direction


    def distance_check(self, dist):
        '''
        Function:
            tests if the total distance from the
            sprite to the target is smaller than the
            ammount of distance that would be normal
            for the sprite to travel
            (this lets the sprite know if it needs
            to slow down. we want it to slow
            down before it gets to it's target)
        Returns:
            bool
        Parameters:
            - self
            - dist
                this is the total distance from the
                sprite to the target
                can be any x,y value pair in
                brackets [x,y]
                or parentheses (x,y)
        '''
        dist_x = dist[0] ** 2 # gets absolute value of the x distance
        dist_y = dist[1] ** 2 # gets absolute value of the y distance
        t_dist = dist_x + dist_y # gets total absolute value distance
        speed = self.speed ** 2 # gets aboslute value of the speed

        if t_dist < (speed): # read function description above
            return True


    def update(self):
        '''
        Function:
            gets direction to move then applies
            the distance to the sprite.center
            ()
        Parameters:
            - self
        '''        
        self.dir = self.get_direction(self.target) # get direction
        if self.dir: # if there is a direction to move
            if self.distance_check(self.dist): # if we need to stop
                self.rect.center = self.target # center the sprite on the target

            else: # if we need to move normal

                self.rect.centerx += (self.dir[0] * self.speed) # calculate speed from direction to move and speed constant
                self.rect.centery += (self.dir[1] * self.speed)
                self.rect.center = (round(self.rect.centerx),round(self.rect.centery)) # apply values to sprite.center

    def move_c(self,distance):
        self.dir = self.get_direction(self.target) # get direction
        if self.dir: # if there is a direction to move

            if self.distance_check(self.dist): # if we need to stop
                self.rect.center = self.target # center the sprite on the target

            else: # if we need to move normal
                self.rect.centerx += (self.dir[0] * self.speed) # calculate speed from direction to move and speed constant
                self.rect.centery += (self.dir[1] * self.speed)
                self.rect.center = (round(self.rect.centerx),round(self.rect.centery)) # apply values to sprite.center
        return distance
def main():

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Test game")
    background_color = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size()).convert()
    background_color.fill((240,50,0))

##    line_points = [] # make a list for points
##    line_color = (0, 255, 255) # color of the lines

    sprite = Sprite() # create the sprite
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sprite.set_position(100,400)

    running = True

    while running:
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                  sprite.move(100)
##                  sprite.move_c(150)
##                sprite.target = event.pos # set the sprite.target to the mouse click position


        screen.blit(background_color, (0,0))

##        sprite.update() # update the sprite

        screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft) # blit the sprite to the screen


        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit() # for a smooth quit
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is one of the move methods, i move the sprite by giving a distance i want to move the sprite. i get the current position the direction of the sprite. to calculate the distance i minus the target by the position and return the position. But when i call this function:

```
sprite.move(50):
```

the sprite doesn't move at all let alone by 50.

```
def move(self, distance):
        if self.target:
            direction =self.get_direction(self.target)
            position = self.get_position() # create a vector from center x,y value
            direction = Vector(direction[0], direction[1]) # and one from the target x,y
            distance = target - position # get total distance between target and position
        return distance
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: Maybe try narrowing your question down. Exactly how didn't your latest approach work? What was the part of code causing the problem?

Comment: The movement of a rectangle, it doesnt move at the moment, even if a distance is passed

Comment: It doesn't look like your move method is actually setting the new position. It only calls "get_position", not "set_position"

Comment: how would i go about improving this then?

Answer (score 0):

Working mainloop

```
while running:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            sprite.target = event.pos # set the sprite.target to the mouse click position


    sprite.move_c(100)

    screen.blit(background_color, (0,0))
    screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft) # blit the sprite to the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

You have call `move_c()` every frame to change sprite position.

By the way - you can put `sprite.update()` in place of `sprite.move_c()` but `sprite.move()` doesn't work.

---

`if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:`

- is true only once when you press mouse button;
- when you keep button pressed it is not true.

---

If you need to do something only when mouse button is pressed you have to do it that way:

```
is_pressed = False

while running:
    clock.tick(30)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            is_pressed = True

        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            is_pressed = False

    if is_pressed:
         sprite.target = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
         sprite.move_c(100)

    screen.blit(background_color, (0,0))
    screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft) # blit the sprite to the screen
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This way sprite follows mouse.

---

**EDIT:**

I have no more previous working code because meanwhile I made modifications - now you can use only arrows (LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN) to move sprite. One click - one move (distance: 100).

This time full code (you have to change bitmap filename)

```
import pygame, math
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class Vector():
    '''

            creates operations to handle vectors such
            as direction, position, and speed
        '''
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self): # used for printing vectors
        return "(%s, %s)"%(self.x, self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 0:
            return self.x
        elif key == 1:
            return self.y
        else:
            raise IndexError("This "+str(key)+" key is not a vector key!")

    def __sub__(self, o): # subtraction
        return Vector(self.x - o.x, self.y - o.y)

    def length(self): # get length (used for normalize)
        return math.sqrt((self.x**2 + self.y**2)) 

    def normalize(self): # divides a vector by its length
        l = self.length()
        if l != 0:
            return (self.x / l, self.y / l)
        return None



class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Class:
            creates a sprite
        Parameters:
            - self
        '''
        self.image = pygame.image.load("ball1.png").convert() # load image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.speed = 10 # movement speed of the sprite
        self.speedX = 0 # speed in x direction
        self.speedY = 0 # speed in y direction
        self.target = None # starts off with no target

    def set_position(self, x,y):
        self.rect.centerx= x
        self.rect.centery= y
        #self.rect.center=(self.rect.centery, self.rect.centery)

    def get_position(self):
        return self.rect.center


    def move(self, distance):
        if self.target:
            direction = self.get_direction(self.target)
            position = self.get_position() # create a vector from center x,y value
            direction = Vector(direction[0], direction[1]) # and one from the target x,y
            distance = self.target - position # get total distance between target and position
        return distance

    def get_direction(self, target):
        '''
        Function:
            takes total distance from sprite.center
            to the sprites target
            (gets direction to move)
        Returns:
            a normalized vector
        Parameters:
            - self
            - target
                x,y coordinates of the sprites target
                can be any x,y coorinate pair in
                brackets [x,y]
                or parentheses (x,y)
        '''
        if self.target: # if the square has a target
            position = Vector(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery) # create a vector from center x,y value
            target = Vector(target[0], target[1]) # and one from the target x,y
            self.dist = target - position # get total distance between target and position

            direction = self.dist.normalize() # normalize so its constant in all directions
            return direction


    def distance_check(self, dist):
        '''
        Function:
            tests if the total distance from the
            sprite to the target is smaller than the
            ammount of distance that would be normal
            for the sprite to travel
            (this lets the sprite know if it needs
            to slow down. we want it to slow
            down before it gets to it's target)
        Returns:
            bool
        Parameters:
            - self
            - dist
                this is the total distance from the
                sprite to the target
                can be any x,y value pair in
                brackets [x,y]
                or parentheses (x,y)
        '''
        dist_x = dist[0] ** 2 # gets absolute value of the x distance
        dist_y = dist[1] ** 2 # gets absolute value of the y distance
        t_dist = dist_x + dist_y # gets total absolute value distance
        speed = self.speed ** 2 # gets aboslute value of the speed

        if t_dist < (speed): # read function description above
            return True


    def update(self):
        '''
        Function:
            gets direction to move then applies
            the distance to the sprite.center
            ()
        Parameters:
            - self
        '''        
        self.dir = self.get_direction(self.target) # get direction
        if self.dir: # if there is a direction to move
            if self.distance_check(self.dist): # if we need to stop
                self.rect.center = self.target # center the sprite on the target

            else: # if we need to move normal

                self.rect.centerx += (self.dir[0] * self.speed) # calculate speed from direction to move and speed constant
                self.rect.centery += (self.dir[1] * self.speed)
                self.rect.center = (round(self.rect.centerx),round(self.rect.centery)) # apply values to sprite.center

    def move_c(self,distance):
        self.dir = self.get_direction(self.target) # get direction
        if self.dir: # if there is a direction to move

            if self.distance_check(self.dist): # if we need to stop
                self.rect.center = self.target # center the sprite on the target

            else: # if we need to move normal
                self.rect.centerx += (self.dir[0] * self.speed) # calculate speed from direction to move and speed constant
                self.rect.centery += (self.dir[1] * self.speed)
                self.rect.center = (round(self.rect.centerx),round(self.rect.centery)) # apply values to sprite.center
        return distance

    def move_d(self):
        if self.target:
            if abs(self.rect.x - self.target.x) > abs(self.speedX):
                self.rect.x += self.speedX
            else:
                self.rect.x = self.target.x

            if abs(self.rect.y - self.target.y) > abs(self.speedY):
                self.rect.y += self.speedY
            else:
                self.rect.y = self.target.y

            if self.rect == self.target:
                self.target = None

    def set_move_left(self, distance):
        if not self.target: 
            self.target = self.rect.copy()
            self.target.centerx -= distance 
            self.speedX = -self.speed
            self.speedY = 0

    def set_move_right(self, distance):
        if not self.target: 
            self.target = self.rect.copy()
            self.target.centerx += distance 
            self.speedX = self.speed
            self.speedY = 0

    def set_move_up(self, distance):
        if not self.target: 
            self.target = self.rect.copy()
            self.target.centery -= distance 
            self.speedX = 0
            self.speedY = -self.speed

    def set_move_down(self, distance):
        if not self.target: 
            self.target = self.rect.copy()
            self.target.centery += distance 
            self.speedX = 0
            self.speedY = self.speed

    def set_move(self, distance, pos):
        if not self.target: 
            self.target = self.rect.copy()
            dx = (pos[0] - self.rect.x)
            dy = (pos[1] - self.rect.y)

            if dx == 0 :
                ay = 0
            else:
                ay = float(distance)/dx

            if dy == 0 :
                ax = 0
            else:
                ax = float(dx)/dy

            self.target.centerx += distance * ax
            self.target.centery += distance * ay
            self.speedX = self.speed * ax
            self.speedY = self.speed * ay

            print "dx/dy:", dx, dy,
            print "ax/ay:", ax, ay

def main():

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Test game")
    background_color = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size()).convert()
    background_color.fill((240,50,0))

##    line_points = [] # make a list for points
##    line_color = (0, 255, 255) # color of the lines

    sprite = Sprite() # create the sprite
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sprite.set_position(100,400)

    running = True

    is_pressed = False

    while running:
        clock.tick(30)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

            elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                #sprite.set_move(100, event.pos)
                pass

            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT:                 
                    sprite.set_move_left(100)
                elif event.key == K_RIGHT:                  
                    sprite.set_move_right(100)
                elif event.key == K_UP:
                    sprite.set_move_up(100)
                elif event.key == K_DOWN:
                    sprite.set_move_down(100)


        sprite.move_d()

        screen.blit(background_color, (0,0))
        screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft) # blit the sprite to the screen
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit() # for a smooth quit

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for this furas! But i dont want the sprite to follow the mouse, i want the sprite to move at a specified distance the user defines, if for example, the user clicks the mouse or even if they press the left arrow. Then the sprite will move. So if the user says move(30) then the sprite should move at a distance of 30.

Comment: I have no more previous working code because meanwhile I made modifications - now you can use (only) arrows (LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN) to move sprite. One click - one move (distance: 100). New (full) code in answer.